# Spring boot - Hive : Driver does not support get/set network timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am connecting to Hive DB using JDBC. Below is my JDBC URL

> jdbc:hive2://hpeeeee.hpc.company.com:8443/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/Users/arun/Downloads/truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=password123;transportMode=http;httpPath=one/default/hive

Am configuring all the JDBC stuffs in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
spring.datasource.url=${hive.url}
spring.datasource.username=${hive.username}
spring.datasource.password=${hive.password}
```

Everything works fine and am able to successfully query my Hive-DB. But what happens is that after some idle-time, the session gets invalid. I couldn't understand why and i noticed this wierd log in my application while booting up (see below)

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method not supported)
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

This is my `build.gradle` (am using spring boot 2.2)

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    //security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'

    //cloud connector
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors'



    implementation (group: 'org.apache.hive', name: 'hive-jdbc', version: '3.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: ''
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: ''
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', module: 'jetty-all'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty'
    }
```

Not sure how to tackle **Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method not supported)** I need to manage network timeout and things like that. Any help

Comment: What actually happens when session gets invalid ? is the application connecting to db ?

Comment: Also pls share pom.xml. Is this a info or error com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method not supported)

Comment: Can you show pom.xml?

Comment: @KarthickM : Its a `info` 

@Seldo97 : I have updated my question with the exact gradle dependency that brings this JDBC driver